# iTerm 2 ZSH font all one color

Tags: vim, colors, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Related to
[iTerm 2 ZSH colors/themes not showed correctly](https://superuser.com/questions/1061181/iterm-2-zsh-colors-themes-not-showed-correctly?newreg=81654bb0c9f8498286ce84e90c4b9c24)

**Machine**: macOS Ventura 13.3

My iTerm2 wont use any other colors than all white (and all black in vim) for my fonts. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Image linked below shows result of

```
print -P '%F{yellow}yellow %F{2}green %1Fred %F{117}light blue'
```

and my iTerm2 Profile Colors settings:

[image: misprintedFontColors]

Also, photo of my iTerm2 Profile Terminal settings:

[image: terminalSettings]

Here is my `.zshrc`:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
 
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
 
# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="afowlermod"
 
# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )
 
# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"
 
# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"
 
# Uncomment one of the following lines to change the auto-update behavior
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode disabled  # disable automatic updates
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode auto      # update automatically without asking
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode reminder  # just remind me to update when it's time
 
# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# zstyle ':omz:update' frequency 13
 
# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"
 
# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"
 
# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"
 
# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"
 
# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# You can also set it to another string to have that shown instead of the default red dots.
# e.g. COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="%F{yellow}waiting...%f"
# Caution: this setting can cause issues with multiline prompts in zsh < 5.7.1 (see #5765)
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"
 
# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"
 
# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"
 
# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder
 
# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git)
 
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
 
# User configuration
 
# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"
 
# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
 
# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi
 
# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
 
# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
```

and my zsh theme:

```
PROMPT='jess %B%F{blue}:: %b%F{green}%3~ $(hg_prompt_info)$(git_prompt_info)%B%(!.%F{red}.%F{blue})»%f%b '
RPS1='%(?..%F{red}%? ↵%f)'

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="%{$fg[yellow]%}‹"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="› %{$reset_color%}"

ZSH_THEME_HG_PROMPT_PREFIX="%{$fg[magenta]%}hg:‹%{$fg[yellow]%}"
ZSH_THEME_HG_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%{$fg[magenta]%}› %{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_HG_PROMPT_DIRTY=" %{$fg[red]%}✗"
ZSH_THEME_HG_PROMPT_CLEAN=""
```

I am also using pathogen to set my vim theme, my `.vimrc` looks like this:

```
set ruler
execute pathogen#infect()
set cursorline
syntax on

filetype plugin indent on

syntax enable

set background=light
colorscheme solarized
```

my `.vim` directory:

```
jess :: ~/.vim » tree
.
├── autoload
│   └── pathogen.vim
└── bundle
    ├── README.mkd
    ├── autoload
    │   └── togglebg.vim
    ├── bitmaps
    │   └── togglebg.png
    ├── colors
    │   └── solarized.vim
    ├── doc
    │   ├── solarized.txt
    │   └── tags
    └── vim-colors-solarized
        ├── README.mkd
        ├── autoload
        │   └── togglebg.vim
        ├── bitmaps
        │   └── togglebg.png
        ├── colors
        │   └── solarized.vim
        └── doc
            ├── solarized.txt
            └── tags
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just the Minimum Contrast setting. It defaults very high, like 85+, but turning it down revealed the colors I expected to see.

[image: Minimum Contrast Settings]